# Using ServiceStack.Text to deserialize a json string to object

Tags: c#, servicestack, anonymous-types, json-deserialization, servicestack-text

I have a JSON string that looks like:

```
"{\"Id\":\"fb1d17c7298c448cb7b91ab7041e9ff6\",\"Name\":\"John\",\"DateOfBirth\":\"\\/Date(317433600000-0000)\\/\"}"
```

I'm trying to deserialize it to `object` (I'm implementing a caching interface)

The trouble I'm having is when I use

```
JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(jsonString);
```

It's coming back as

> "{Id:6ed7a388b1ac4b528f565f4edf09ba2a,Name:John,DateOfBirth:/Date(317433600000-0000)/}"

Is that right?

I can't assert on anything... I also can't use the dynamic keyword....

Is there a way to return an anonymous object from the ServiceStack.Text library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) in **ServiceStack.Common** is the preferred way to deserialize adhoc JSON with unknown types since it will return the relevant C# object based on the JSON payload, e.g deserializing an object with:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("{\"Id\":\"..\"}");
```

Will return a loose-typed `Dictionary<string,object>` which you can cast to access the JSON object dynamic contents:

```
if (obj is Dictionary<string,object> dict) {
    var id = (string)dict["Id"];
}
```

But if you prefer to use [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) typed JSON serializers, it can't deserialize into an object since it doesn't know what type to deserialize into so it leaves it as a string which is an object.

Consider using [ServiceStack's dynamic APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json) to deserialize arbitrary JSON, e.g:

```
var json = @"{\"Id\":\"fb1d17c7298c448cb7b91ab7041e9ff6\",
          \"Name\":\"John\",\"DateOfBirth\":\"\\/Date(317433600000-0000)\\/\"}";

var obj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
obj.Get<Guid>("Id").ToString().Print();
obj.Get<string>("Name").Print();
obj.Get<DateTime>("DateOfBirth").ToLongDateString().Print();
```

Or parsing into a dynamic:

```
dynamic dyn = DynamicJson.Deserialize(json);
string id = dyn.Id;
string name = dyn.Name;
string dob = dyn.DateOfBirth;
"DynamicJson: {0}, {1}, {2}".Print(id, name, dob);
```

Another option is to tell ServiceStack to convert object types to a Dictionary, e.g:

```
JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;
var map = (Dictionary<string, object>)json.FromJson<object>();
map.PrintDump();
```

Comment: Looks good... when I do this, the "properties" of my object come back (for example) as : [0] {[Name, John]} - an array of key / value... is that right?

Comment: I wanted to try ServiceStack's dynamic API but for me there isn't .Get<T>(key) method of JsonObject. I only installed "Install-Package ServiceStack.Text". Can you advice what I may be missing?

Comment: @LukAss741 [`.Get<T>` is an instance extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/9c2a8adca539e8d85082612819e1cebb8f99be51/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonObject.cs#L20), please go through the [linked json parsing examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json) on the home page.