# Deserialize Json into a dynamic object with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack-text

I am using [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to deserialize json into a dynamic object.

I'm encountering an error when trying to deserialize the following json:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "title":["test"],
        "_version_":1480260331707039744}]
  }}
```

The json above is a string and this is how I am trying to deserialize it:

```
DynamicJson dyn = DynamicJson.Deserialize(json);    
var response = dyn.response;
```

But I get an error saying: **dyn does not contain a definition for 'response'**

---

`dyn` does return a type of `ServiceStack.DynamicJson` with the following value (from debugger):

```
{"response_header":"{\n    \"status\":0,\n    \"QTime\":0,\n    \"params\":{\n      \"q\":\"*:*\",\n      \"size\":\"0\",\n      \"indent\":\"True\",\n      \"start\":\"0\",\n      \"wt\":\"json\",\n      \"return-fields\":\"\"}}","response":"{\"numFound\":1,\"start\":0,\"docs\":[\n      {\n        \"id\":\"1\",\n        \"title\":[\"test\"],\n        \"_version_\":1480260331707039744}]\n  }"}    ServiceStack.DynamicJson
```

According to the answer here: [Using ServiceStack.Text to deserialize a json string to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600968/using-servicestack-text-to-deserialize-a-json-string-to-object) that's how its done, but what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though `DynamicJson.Deserialize` does in fact return an instance of `DynamicJson`, you have to declare `dyn` as `dynamic` to treat it dynamically:

```
dynamic dyn = DynamicJson.Deserialize(json);    
var response = dyn.response;
```

According to the documentation for `DynamicObject` (which `DynamicJson` inherits from):

> In C#, to enable dynamic behavior for instances of classes derived from the DynamicObject class, **you must use the dynamic keyword**.

If the expression isn't of type `dynamic`, static binding will still occur, which is why you're seeing the error.